# header links by role laravel-admin

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-admin

I use https://laravel-admin.org/docs/en/README on my site.

I have a general header in the admin panel, which displays all the sections that can be edited, here is the code:

```
<?php foreach(Admin::menuLinks() as $link) { ?>
<?php if (in_array($link['uri'], ['users', 'posts', 'comments'])) {?> 
    <a class="sidebar-toggle sidebar-toggle-link" role="button" href="<?= admin_url($link['uri']) ?>"><i class="fa <?= $link['icon'] ?>"></i>
        <?= admin_trans ($link['title']) ?>
    </a>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

I won’t throw all the header code, since it’s standard, there is only a code for links to sections, but if necessary I can throw it off.

So, I have 3 partitions. Each section will have its own admin, who will have a corresponding role. Now all admins with roles see all links in the header, but I need to hide them and make sure that the admin sees only the link to which he has a role with rights. How can I do such a check in the header? To display these links depending on the user's role.

I didn't find anything similar in the documentation.

There is supposedly how to get a user role, but how can I use it here `Admin::user()->roles;`

Comment: I have a separate admin_roles table which is related to admin_users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

if you want to show link by role

```
@foreach(Admin::menuLinks() as $link)
    @if (Admin::user()->isRole('developer'))
        //if user role is developer
    @endif
@endforeach
```

if you want to show the link by permission

```
@foreach(Admin::menuLinks() as $link)
    @if (Admin::user()->can('create-post'))
        //if user has permission to create post
    @endif
@endforeach
```

check the documentation for more details https://laravel-admin.org/docs/en/permission